# 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder

Tags: python, json, python-requests, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to list the folders for a team member on our Dropbox Business account.

https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder requires that we add the `Dropbox-API-Select-User` header, but it does not seem to be working.

This is my code so far:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder"

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer MY_TOKEN",
    "Dropbox-API-Select-User": "dbid:ACCOUNT_ID"
    }

data = {
    "path": "/",
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
r.raise_for_status()
print(r.json())
```

Note that the `json=` argument in the `post()` function sets the content type to `application/json` so that should be correct.

The code above raises an exception:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder
```

I have tried using the team member ID (`bdmid:`) instead of the account ID but got the same error.

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

I'm using Python 3.6 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be `POST`? To me it would seem more appropriate for a *list*-type call to use `GET` instead? But I've never used the Dropbox API, so I have no idea what the base requirements are.

Comment: Provide the right path and then Try again ... also add one more header Content-Type: application/json"

Comment: Isn't there a Python client that will do all this for you?

Comment: @Jitendra: isn't "/" a valid path? It should be the root directory. Also, please see my note in the question that the content type is already set to "application/json" by using the `json` argument

Comment: @blokeley: set path to {"path":""} and it would work :)

Comment: @idjaw: Dropbox uses POST for most requests. See https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/03/limitations-of-the-get-method-in-http/

Comment: @idjaw: I could use the SDK for this trivial example but my app does some things that mean raw requests will be better

Comment: @blokeley Thanks for the link! At least there's an explanation :). Sorry don't have much to offer in terms of help for this.

Comment: @Jitendra: I'll try that when I'm coding again tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Also, are we supposed to use the user account id (dbid:) or the Dropbox Business team member id (dbmid:)?

Comment: @Jitendra: {"path": ""} gets the same HTTP 400 error

Comment: @blokeley : remove "Dropbox-API-Select-User" header. Can you please show the full error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I should note that we do recommend using the official [Dropbox API v2 Python SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python) as it takes care of a lot of the underlying networking/formatting work for you. That said, you can certainly use the underlying [HTTPS endpoints](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation) directly like this if you prefer.

Anyway, when dealing with issues like this, be sure to print out the body of the response itself, as it will contain a more helpful error message. You can do so like this:

`print(r.text)`

In this case with this code, that yields an error message:

`Error in call to API function "files/list_folder": Invalid select user id format`

Another issue is that with API v2, the root path is supposed to be specified as empty string, `""`:

`Error in call to API function "files/list_folder": request body: path: Specify the root folder as an empty string rather than as "/".`

That's because when using the [member file access](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams#teams-member-file-access) feature like this, you are supposed to supply the member ID, not the account ID.

So, fixing those issues, the working code looks this:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder"

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer MY_TOKEN",
    "Dropbox-API-Select-User": "dbmid:MEMBER_ID"
    }

data = {
    "path": "",
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
print(r.text)
r.raise_for_status()
print(r.json())
```

---

Edited to add, if you want to use the [Dropbox API v2 Python SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python) for this, you would use [`DropboxTeam.as_user`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.DropboxTeam.as_user) like this:

```
import dropbox

dbx_team = dropbox.DropboxTeam("MY_TOKEN")
dbx_user = dbx_team.as_user("dbmid:MEMBER_ID")

print(dbx_user.files_list_folder(""))
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks.  The combination of 1) using the member id and 2) the non-standard empty string "" instead of the standard slash "/" for the root directory worked.  I still couldn't see how to call the dropbox SDK functions as a team member though.  The dropbox SDK appears to be written for individual users, not Dropbox Business

Comment: I edited my answer with a sample for the SDK. Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent.  Now I can see the point of the SDK! I wish there was documentation with Dropbox Business SDK examples somewhere. The one-page dump of the docstrings seen on readthedocs isn't very enlightening